# Cambio de Caracteres a Factores

Tags: r, bucle-for, caracteres

Buen día, Estoy generando un proceso sobre un dataframe en R usando un ciclo for. Todo se ejecuta bien pero el problema radica en que en el dataframe resultante los valores que se encontraban en carácter se cambien a enteros. El código es el siguiente:

```
v6 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=6, ncol=23))
names(v6.1)<-names(v17)
for (i in 1:6)
{
v6.1[i,] <- dfpmax[dfpmax$codigo == v5$codigo[i] & dfpmax$año == v3$año,]
}
```

La forma en la que busco que sea la visualización de los datos es la siguiente

```
Codigo           Nombre    Estacion    Latitud  Longitud    Altitud
35070170         NAZARETH [35070170] 4.733333 -73.20000     400
35080080   PIEDRA CAMPANA [35080080] 4.860389 -73.23408     450
35087070 CASA DE MAQUINAS [35087070] 4.900000 -73.23333     450
35080140         CACHIPAY [35080140] 4.883333 -73.25000     850
35070180      SANTA MARIA [35070180] 4.860778 -73.25675     850
35070450      SITIO PRESA [35070450] 4.900000 -73.30000    1210
```

Lo que obtengo es lo siguiente

```
Código    Nombre Estación    Latitud  Longitud    Altitud
35070170         15          4.733333 -73.20000     400
35080080         6           4.860389 -73.23408     450
35087070         7           4.900000 -73.23333     450
35080140         4           4.883333 -73.25000     850
35070180         2           4.860778 -73.25675     850
35070450         35          4.900000 -73.30000    1210
```

Como se evidencia mi problema es que en este caso en el dataframe resultado donde deberían aparecer nombres aparecen números enteros, estos es lo que busco evitar, o saber por que sucede durante al asignación en el ciclo for.
Agradezco el tiempo prestado y saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que `dfpmax$Nombre` es un `factor` y `v6` no tiene la misma estructura que `dfpmax`, por lo que, cuando haces:

```
v6.1[i,] <- dfpmax[dfpmax$codigo == v5$codigo[i] & dfpmax$año == v3$año,]
```

En el caso de los factores, se termina asignando el valor numérico y no el `factor` en sí.

Mi sugerencias, es que crees `v6` como una copia fiel de `dfpmax` sin datos, `v6 <- dfpmax[0,]`:

```
v6 <- dfpmax[0,]
names(v6)<-names(v17)
for (i in 1:6) {
    v6[i,] <- dfpmax[dfpmax$codigo == v5$codigo[i] & dfpmax$año == v3$año,]
}
```

Comment: Muchas, Gracias